# foreach array insert to database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, foreach, composite-primary-key

I have 3 tables. category,ingredient and category_ingredient. now i want the id's of category and ingredient to be inserted to category_ingredient. but i get an error like this:[image]

this is my code:

VIEW:add_ingredients.php

```
<?php echo form_open('dashboard/uploadIngredients', 'class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">

            <select class="form-control" name="ingredient_category">

                <option selected disabled>Select Ingredient Category</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <?php foreach($this->products_model->getCategory() as $row): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->category_id ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="ingredients" rows="5" placeholder="Ingredients (EX. onion, oil, pasta)"></textarea> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-positive" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save Ingredient</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

CONTROLLER: dashboard.php

```
public function uploadIngredients()
 {

   foreach(explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredients')) as $key => $value)
    {
        $saveData[] = array('ingredient_id' => null,
                            'name'  => trim($value)
        );  
    }

    // var_dump($saveData); die();
    $ingredient_id = $this->products_model->saveIngredients($saveData);
    foreach (explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredient_category')) as $key => $value)
    {
        $joinData[] = array(
                            'ingredient_id'     => $ingredient_id,
                            'category_id'       => trim($value)
        );
    }
        //var_dump($joinData); die();
        $this->products_model->saveCategoryIngredients($joinData);

        redirect('dashboard/add_ingredients');

    }/* end of upload_file() */
```

MODEL: products_model.php

```
 public function saveIngredients($data)
  {
    foreach($data as $row => $value)
        {
            $this->db->insert('ingredient', $value);
            $insert_id[] = $this->db->insert_id();  
        }

    return $insert_id;
}

 public function saveCategoryIngredients($data)
{
     foreach($data as $row => $value)
        {
            $this->db->insert('category_ingredient', $value);
            $insert_id[] = $this->db->insert_id();  
        }

    return $insert_id;
}
```

[image]

Comment: is your filed "ingredient_category" a comma separated  one ?

Comment: oh no sir. because i just want to get the id of that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're treating `$ingredient_id` as a string but it's an array. I usually name my variables with the type I'm expecting so I don't get confused... for example, `$ingredient_id_array`.

```
 // var_dump($saveData); die();
$ingredient_id_array = $this->products_model->saveIngredients($saveData);
foreach (explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredient_category')) as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ( $ingredient_id_array as $key => $str ){
            $joinData[] = array(
                                'ingredient_id'     => intval( $str ),
                                'category_id'       => intval( trim($value) )
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: sir i tried your code and when i var_dump($joinData); die();  its like this                        array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'ingredient_id' => int 9
      'category_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'ingredient_id' => int 10
      'category_id' => string '2' (length=1)

Comment: the category_id is still a string :((((

Comment: sir it is still a string in category_id

Comment: Yeah okay then convert it to a number -> intval(  )... looks like you should review your datatypes and take a bit more care naming your variables.  Your short code is nice but it isn't clear if you pass it on to the next person

Comment: it is now a number but it didn't save on my table category_ingredient sir :(

Comment: Great.  I noticed one more thing... Are you sure you need the AUTO_INCREMENT on a field where you're inserting data ( ingredient_id )?  You should have a 3rd column for 'category_ingredient' that is unique and AUTO_INCREMENTS

Comment: yes it works sir. thank you so much!!!! you are my savior. but i have another problem sir on how to make a condition. i want to add ingredient but add a condition that if the ingredient and category is the same then i cant add an ingredient

Comment: Then just put the condition before you add the data to the $joinData Array.

Comment: i tried to condition using comparing the ingredient_id and category_id but my problem is my ingredient_id is auto incremented so it will not work sir

Comment: But you're comparing values _before_ you put them in the database... And I still don't know why you're auto_incrementing and inserting a value... it makes no sense.  Did you read my comment above about it?

Comment: sorry i just read it now. what do u mean by that? u mean i will add another column in my table category_ingredient?

Comment: i auto incremented ingredient_id so that i will identify in table ingredient what is that ingredient by name. in my category table i have data that categorize by 1 for dessert 2 halal 3 for vegetarian. i have a project in filtering ingredient by category sir

Comment: I'm sorry but you're confusing me.  I think you have a new question to ask now, with different examples .  This one looks solved to me.

Comment: You should also mark this as the correct answer :).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller

```
public function uploadIngredients()
 {

   foreach(explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredients')) as $key => $value)
    {
        $saveData = array('ingredient_id' => null,
                            'name'  => $value1
        );  
        $ingredient_id = $this->products_model->saveIngredients($saveData);
       $value1=$this->input->post('ingredient_category');
        $joinData = array(
                            'ingredient_id'     => $ingredient_id,
                            'category_id'       => trim($value)
        );

         $this->products_model->saveCategoryIngredients($joinData);
    }

        redirect('dashboard/add_ingredients');

    }
```

On Your Model

```
    public function saveCategoryIngredients($data)
{

            $this->db->insert('category_ingredient', $value);
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();  


    return $insert_id;
}
```

public function saveIngredients($data)
  {

```
        $this->db->insert('ingredient', $value);
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();  


return $insert_id;
```

}

Comment: the data is save ingredient but i cant insert the id of 2 tables ingredient and category to category_ingredient :( it doesn't work sir :(

Comment: and also the code u give sir only insert 1 data. i was trying to insert multiple data in my table sir

Comment: for example in my text area i want to add ingredient like Onion,Apple,Garlic so in my database table ingredient it is exploded and there ids are not the same.

Comment: it only insert 1 ingredient not multiple ingredient sir

Comment: try to get value what you exploded

for example 
$abc=explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredients');
print_r($abc);

Comment: in my textarea i want to input multiple ingredients and i use comma so in my controller i use explode(',') and it is successfully inserted in my table ingredient but not on my table category_ingredient :(

Comment: $a= $this->input->post('ingredient_category');
$b=explode(',',$a);
print_r($b);
try this

Comment: sir it only insert 1 value in ingredient_category when i var_dump($b); die();

Comment: what was print on your browser

Answer (score 0):

controller code

```
public function uploadIngredients()
{
   $ingredients_post = explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredients'));    
    foreach( $ingredients_post as $key => $value)
    {
        $saveData = array('ingredient_id' => null,'name'  => trim($value)
        );  
        $ingredient_id = $this->products_model->saveIngredients($saveData);
        $joinData = array(
                            'ingredient_id'     => $ingredient_id,
                            'category_id'       => $this->input->post('ingredient_category')
                          );
        $this->products_model->saveCategoryIngredients($joinData);

    }
    redirect('dashboard/add_ingredients');
}
```

model

```
 public function saveCategoryIngredients($data)
{

            $this->db->insert('category_ingredient', $value);

}
public function saveIngredients($data) {

        $this->db->insert('ingredient', $value);
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();  


return $insert_id;
}
```

Comment: maam i tried your code but it only inserted 1 value :(

Comment: i have uodated the code could you please check again, if its not working please let me knw the value of  $ingredients_post